# ITextsharp c# field calculations

Tags: c#, javascript, pdf, itext, field

Is there way creating automatically calculating fields with iTextsharp? I have tried doing this with javascript but the problem is that field values only get updated during certain events (ex. mouseover, mouseup). If I use events the field values only update when I move mouse cursor. They don't get updated if I write a value to field, then move mouse cursor somewhere else and then press enter. They get updated when I move cursor back to the field. Afaik there is no event like "field  value changed" or something similiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "on changed" event like there is in HTML, however there are "on focus" and "on blur" events so you can pretty easily write your own. The code below shows this off. It first creates a global JavaScript variable (which is not needed, you can discard that line, it just helps me think). Then it creates a standard text field and sets two actions, the `Fo` (focus) event and the `Bl` (blur) event. You can find these events and others in the PDF standard section 12.6.3 table 194.

In the focus event I'm just storing the current text field's value. In the blur event I'm comparing the store value with the new value and then just alerting if they are the same or different. If you have a bunch of fields you'll probably want to use a global array instead of individual variables, too. See the code comments for more information. This was tested against iTextSharp 5.4.2.0.

```
//Our test file
var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf");

//Standard PDF creation, nothing special
using (var fs = new FileStream(testFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
            doc.Open();

            //Add a global variable. This line is 100% not needed but it helps me think more clearly
            writer.AddJavaScript(PdfAction.JavaScript("var first_name = '';", writer));

            //Create a text field
            var tf = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(50, 50, 300, 100), "first_name");
            //Give it some style and default text
            tf.BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_INSET;
            tf.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
            tf.Text = "First Name";

            //Get the underlying form field object
            var tfa = tf.GetTextField();

            //On focus (Fo) store the value in our global variable
            tfa.SetAdditionalActions(PdfName.FO, PdfAction.JavaScript("first_name = this.getField('first_name').value;", writer));

            //On blur (Bl) compare the old value with the entered value and do something if they are the same/different
            tfa.SetAdditionalActions(PdfName.BL, PdfAction.JavaScript("var old_value = first_name; var new_value = this.getField('first_name').value; if(old_value != new_value){app.alert('Different');}else{app.alert('Same');}", writer));

            //Add our form field to the document
            writer.AddAnnotation(tfa);

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```